# Change Binding Source Issue

Tags: wpf

I want to create Binding only once but keep changing its `Source`.

Here is my code.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TempDummyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TempDummy", typeof(object), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public object Source
{
    get; set;
}

public object GetValueFromBinding(object data)
{
    if (this.BindingData == null)
    {
        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.Path = this.BindingPath;
        b.Source = this.Source;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, TempDummyProperty, b);
        this.BindingData = b;
    }

    this.Source = data;
    BindingExpression be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, TempDummyProperty);
    be.UpdateTarget();
    return this.GetValue(TempDummyProperty);
}
```

However when I call this method I always get null returned.

```
GetValueFromBinding(this.DataContext);
```

Seems the Binding is not noticing that source was changed.

How to get this straight without always creating new Binding object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Binding` is merely the description of the binding; it is not the application of the binding.  The `Binding` class is a markup extension which produces a `BindingExpression`, and *that* is the expression-based value that gets applied to the property.

Modifying a `Binding` will not have any effect on existing applications of that binding, and a `BindingExpression` cannot be modified once it has been applied.

A couple observations about your code:

1. You set `b.Source = this.Source`, then later update `this.Source`; this will not affect `b.Source` in any way.
2. `UpdateTarget()` tells the binding to manually update the value of the target property from the source property.  It will not check back with the `Binding` which produced it and see if the source has changed.

If you want to keep your `Binding` around and update its `Source`, you will have to reapply the binding each time (e.g., with `SetBinding`), or the underlying `BindingExpression` will not reflect the change.

Comment: I am modifing the source property of my helper object. Just like swapping datacontext and binding still works so shall my swapping work too. It doesnt though :-(

Comment: But you're not even updating the binding source... see updated answer.

Comment: I know I am not the question was how do I?